# Error:genymotion virtualization engine not found

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I keep getting the following error:

***genymotion virtualization engine not found***

***Unable to load VirtualBox engine***

please help me to fix this error. I have tried every option

1.Reinstall the genymotion and virtualbox

2.restarted the virtual box.

But these things doesnot work for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: what version of Genymotion, is "2.3.0"?

Comment: I don't believe this question is offtopic. This question DOES directly involve a tool used primarily for programming (Genymotion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please be more specific:

- What OS are you using?
- When do you get this error?
- Are you able to start VirtualBox and create a VM in there?

Try the following steps to fix errors:

- Check for the Virtualisation Feature in your Computers BIOS. ENABLE it!!

still not working?

- Remove all VMs in Genymotion
- Install VirtualBox > 4.3.18 (they fixed some bugs there)

Comment: I am using windows 7 ultimate 64 bit. I get this error when i am trying to open genymotion for the first time.I am using Virtual box version 4.2.12.                                                    **Note: Previously i had a version of genymotion and it worked fine but after reinstall this with a new version of genymotion and virtual box the error comes in to play. So kindly help me to recover this asap.

Comment: I've edited my answer above. I'm pretty sure you haven't configured your BIOS yet. Regards

Comment: I've done everything you and other people suggest but the problem consists. Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem. Enabling visualization in the bios didn't help. What could be done? @DennisBriner

Comment: What Versions of OS, VirtualBox or Genymotion are you using?
Did you remove all the VMs and reinstalled VirtualBox after it(the newest Version)? @h8pathak

Comment: 64 bit Win 7, VB 4.3.2, Genymotion 2.4.0. I have tried reinstalling Virtual Box and Genymotion earlier. I also tried restarting the Virtual Box but in vain. @DennisBriner

Comment: in that case i cannot help you. if you really removed the VMs before reinstalling and than created new VMs with genymotion I am clueless...sry bro

Comment: may it help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187024/geny-motion-virtualization-engine-not-found-error/34104685#34104685