# Genymotion: Virtualization engine not found

Tags: genymotion

Genymotion virtualization engine not found.  Plugin aborted.
I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.
Help me fix this error please.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me and fixed it using this steps

1. Remove all VMs in Genymotion
2. Install VirtualBox > 4.3.18 (they fixed some bugs there)

you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757546/errorgenymotion-virtualization-engine-not-found) answer for more elaborate solution.
hope it helps.

-cheers / happy codings

Answer (score 0):

If you installed VirtualBox and it still doesn't find virtualization engine, may be you miss installing networking:

[image: VirtualBox]