# Genymotion not working on windows 10

Tags: android, virtualbox, emulation, genymotion

i have done a fresh installed windows 10

Genymotion is not working,

Visualization engine not found, plugin loading aborted

1. i have tried fresh install of Genymotion,Virtual Box separately
2. changing ip address of virtual network host
3. tried installing bundle package available on Genymotion website
4. tried restarting pc after installation of GenyMotion & Virtual box

on Genymotion log file , getting this
[Genymotion Log file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CEDBFD90C892A018!633&authkey=!AKP5LGGVh-7KnT0&ithint=file%2Clog)

can anyone please help me out ?

## Solved

## Step 1

Uninstall genymotion and virtual box and remove all the leftover

## Step 2

Enable Hyper-V [Enable Hyper-v on Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2087-hyper-v-virtualization-setup-use-windows-10-a.html)(Follow step 2)

## Step 3

Restart

## Step 4

Follow these steps [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32101818/1110999)

its working fine now

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26758163/3368533

Answer (score 1):

I have just managed to resolve this issue on my environment. 
after trying every suggestion I could find on the net, the only thing that solved this problem involved the following steps .

1. deleting all VM, from the oracle virtual Box .
2. uninstalling generation
3. reinstalling the latest version .

please verify that no remains (Configuration files or other files ) are left after uninstalling the applications.

hope this will help .

Comment: you have installed genymotion and virtual box separately or bundle that is available on genymotion website ?

Comment: I have installed the bundle.