# Genymotion is not working in Windows 10 for Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-10, virtualbox, genymotion

I have tried everything(reinstalled, open as administrator, etc) and it's still not opening the Android 5.x and 6.x emulator.

The error message is :

> Unable to start the virtual device.
>   The virtual device got no IP address.
>   The VirtualBox DHCP server has not assigned an IP address to the virtual device. To find a solution, please start Virtual Box.

I have followed this [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781326/genymotion-error-after-windows-10-upgrade/32101818#32101818) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913609/genymotion-not-working-on-windows-10) but the error message keeps.

I'm using a Windows 10 Pro.

Any other tip without the need of reinstalling the Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Hey man I think I caught your problem.

1) **Please Open VirtualBox and and Then right click on your Virutal Machine.**

2) **Select Settings.**

3) **Open** `General` **Setting from the left panel.**

4) **Open the Basic tab.**

5) Choose **Linux** from the `Type` option.

6) Then choose ***Other Linux(64-bit)*** in the **Version** Section.

*I have tried the option of 32-bit mode in my PC and the same problem happens as you asked in your question. So, select 64-bit mode to make it run.*

> **Note:** Android 5.x and 6.x are based on the 64-bit architecture. If you
>   selected the Other Linux(32-bit) option. Then Virtual Box will try to
>   emulate a 64-bit program in a 32-bit virtual machine type, which is
>   not possible.
>
> So, Please make sure that you have selected the Other Linux(64-bit)
>   option for Android Versions higher than 5.x. (You can run Android
>   versions upto 4.x in the 32-bit mode.)

[image]

> **Old Answer:**
>
> No, You don't need to reinstall windows. It is not an operating system
>   fault.
>
> I faced this problem.
>
> **It is due to the Antivirus Program.**
>
> If you have any antivirus program then ***just disable it and TRY
>   AGAIN***.
>
> You also **don't need to set any compatibility mode.**
>
> Currently, I am using **Genymotion**(Version 2.6.0) and
>   **VirtualBox**(Version 5.0.12 r104815) in Windows 10 Pro without any error.

Comment: The only "anti vírus" that i have at the moment is Windows Defender, i've disabled it but the same DHCP error keep ocurring!
It's being a pain in the neck =/

Comment: Also send me the screenshot of the VirtualBox Window. This is very important.

Comment: Man, you hit the nail on the head with the Linx OS Version.
It was selected 32-Bits and I didn't know that Android 5-6.x uses a 64-Bit version(I'm sorry).
After this little change, everything is working now.

Comment: welcome sir, I know that headache because I had faced the same problem. And the interesting thing is that no solution is given anywhere on this problem. But fortunatly, after reading some logs and  tweaking I found the solution.

Comment: Whenever anything blocks your path, just ask me...I am ready to help.

Comment: Definitely this tip could be on Genymotion Tutorial's settings.