# GENY MOTION Virtualization engine not found ERROR

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, genymotion, hybrid-mobile-app, hyper-v

**I am having this problem for a while,
I searched a lot on the internet,**

The problem is when I emulate hybird app in the android geny motion emulator it say 'Virtualization engine not found'.

what I found on the internet is to enable Hyper-V in windows feature and reinstall VB host network adapter but noting works for me. And also Virtual Box is not showing any Host Only Networks.

> And when I create any Host Network in VBox it is not there on
>   reopening the VBox.

- GenyMotion version 2.5.3.
- VBox version 5.
- OS Windows 10 pro Updated.
  (the problem is same on other OSs)

[image: Attached Image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Genymotion not working on windows 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913609/genymotion-not-working-on-windows-10) and/or [Genymotion error after windows 10 upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781326/genymotion-error-after-windows-10-upgrade/32101818)

Comment: I saw both of these,they also didn't work for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### I solved this issue. It's working fine now.

I'm using:

```
+ Window 10
+ VirtualBox-5.0.2-102096-Win
+ Genymotion-2.5.3
```

**Step 1**: We should set **Run as this program as an administrator** & **Compatibility mode Windows 8** for those file.

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
    + VBoxHeadless.exe
    + VBoxManage.exe
    + VirtualBox.exe
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
    + genymotion.exe
```

**Step 2**: My Computer -> Manage-> Device Manager-> Network adapters

Remove all items with name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethenet Adapter #...

**Step 3**: Open Virtual Box and go to File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host Only Networks

Remove all and create new host with information:

```
Adapter Tab:
    IPv4 Address:        192.168.1.201
    IPv4 Network Mask:   255.255.255.0
DHCP Server Tab:
    Server Address:      192.168.1.100
    Server Mask:         255.255.255.0
    Lower Address Bound: 192.168.1.101
    Upper Address Bound: 192.168.1.199
```

**Step 4**: Run Genymotion again. It's will work.

### [> Screenshots](http://s1187.photobucket.com/user/bjngboong/slideshow/Genymotion)

Comment: Worked for me, but at Step 3: I have to change/ modify one of the existing hosts and remove the others, because I can't create a new one! (Win10 ftw...)

Comment: Yeah, like @basti but it not works. I did reinstall Virtual Box and it works

Comment: gald to help you :)

Comment: your are very welcome @TAHATEMURII!!

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

Step 1: Run VirtualBox as administrator

Step 2: Go to File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host Only Networks

Step 3: Add a new one or just edit an old one:

Adapter Tab:
    IPv4 Address:        192.168.x.201
    IPv4 Network Mask:   255.255.255.0
DHCP Server Tab:
    Server Address:      192.168.x.100
    Server Mask:         255.255.255.0
    Lower Address Bound: 192.168.x.101
    Upper Address Bound: 192.168.x.199

credit: http://www.stackoverflow.dluat.com/questions/30951147/genymotion-unable-to-load-virtualbox-engine-on-windows-10