# Virtual Box fails when trying to run geny motion on windows 10

Tags: android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion

I have tried avrything thats given in this particular help [Genymotion error after windows 10 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781326/genymotion-error-after-windows-10-upgrade) 
and a lot of others too. I have installed and uninstalled both `genymotion` and `VBOX` multiple times. I dont know what seems to be causing this probles. Ever since i have upgraded to win 10 this is occuring. I am attaching screen shots too.

[image: Error]
[image: Error2]

Comment: I have the adapter that is that shown i the screen shot, but it still does'nt work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GENY MOTION Virtualization engine not found ERROR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187024/geny-motion-virtualization-engine-not-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using GenyMotion 2.0.3 and VirtualBox 4.3.6. My problem was I have an existing host-only adaptor that is used by Vagrant. I can't simply delete it, it will trash my Vagrant VM.

Create a new host-only adaptor in the Virtual Box global settings.
Give it a separate address space from any existing host-only adaptors. For example, I set mine up as follows, where I also have a vboxnet0 (used by Vagrant) that uses 192.168.56.x

name: vboxnet1 IPV4 address: 192.168.57.1 mask: 255.255.255.0

DHCP: address 192.168.57.100 mask: 255.255.255.0 low bounds: 192.168.57.101 high bound: 192.168.57.254

Then, edit your existing GenyMotion VM to use this host-only adaptor, and restart it from GenyMotion.

Good luck!