# unable to load virtualbox engine genymotion windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, genymotion

I know, already much information appeared through this question. But unfortunately, taking into account them, I so not succeeded to start genymotion. Now, it installed genymotion 2.6 and virtualbox 5.0.10.

What I did for start:

1.Trying to install genymotion v2.0.3: geny start, but emulator not working and cant install device with android > 5

2. Trying to install other version of virtual box: from 4.3 to 5.0.11
3. Before, I had installed VMWorkstation. I removed it: no result
4. In bios virtualization is enabled
5. In VirtualBox in newtwork preferences trying to add new host-only network: I could not do it, because there was an error (Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) Component: HostNetworkInterfaceWrap Interface: IHostNetworkInterface {455f8c45-44a0-a470-ba20-27890b96dba9})
6. trying to start with comparability with Windows 7/8/8.1 : no result
7. trying to start with administrator mode (geny and VMBox): no result

Maybe, someone faced with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GENY MOTION Virtualization engine not found ERROR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187024/geny-motion-virtualization-engine-not-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

Hi this might help you:

You must go the VirtualMachine preferences under File in the menu. Then choose the Network setting, then Host-only Networks.

You can use the - button to delete all of the Ethernet Adapters that you have there.

Then create a new one and use the following settings:

IPv4 Address : 192.168.1.201 IPv4 network mask : 255.255.255.0

Then in the DHCP server tab: Address: 192.168.1.100 mask: 255.255.255.0 Lower address: 192.168.1.101 Upper address : 192.168.1.199

Check to see which Ethernet adapter # you have now set up - this might be important later on. Click OK for all the open boxes or save whatever you have.

Then try and run genyMotion again. This worked for me.

There is one more thing you may have to do if this still doesnt work. Go to Network and sharing centre . Change adapter settings and disable all the Ethernet connections EXCEPT for the Ethernet adapter you have just created.

I hope that helps Daniel

Comment: In preferences no host only networks, and when I create new it show error (5 item in my question)

Comment: In Preferences on the left there is a list General, Input, Network- click on Network, there are two tabs NAT network and HostOnly - choose host only

Comment: I'm telling you, I have the same error as in 5 item in my question. (Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) Component: HostNetworkInterfaceWrap)